# Combine Query Result into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have sql query that result data like this one

```
Name        | City
-------------------
Frank       | London
Sebastian   | New York
```

I want to merge that result into a single row and column like this one

```
Frank;London;Sebastian;New York
```

How do I resolve this query problem? Thanks before

Comment: can you post the query that gets that data ?

Comment: This would breach numerous SQL Best Practices.  It's a code smell.  Or whatever other terminology you want for "you probably shouldn't even Want to do this".  What's the ***purpose*** behind your technical requirement?  If you explain why you want to do this, how it will be used, we may be able to provide an alternative, and/or detailed examples on why this is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

By default SSMS prints results in grid format. One of the options is to print the results to text. Click this button on the menu or press the shortcut "CTRL+T". This will print tab delimited results by default, instead of the semicolon delimited results that you want. This can be changed from the Query->Query Options->Results-> Text->Output Format menu or by using "CTRL+H" in a text editor (like Notepad) to find and replace all tabs with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server that should do the work:

```
SELECT ';'+rtrim(Name)+';'+rtrim(City)
FROM Table
FOR XML PATH('')
```

in oracle you don't have XML PATH('') syntax but you can concatenate a field like that for example:

```
SELECT ';' || WM_CONCAT(name||';'||City) AS Result
FROM   table
```

Note that in Oracle 12c WM_CONCAT is deprecated but you can use ListaAgg

```
SELECT LISTAGG(Name||City,';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY aColumn DESC) FROM TABLE
```

cheers

Comment: Is there a way I can use syntax like FOR XML PATH('') in Oracle Query?

Comment: i modified my answer to include even oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select stuff ( (select distinct ';'+t1.col2
                from table t cross apply
                     ( values (name), (city) ) t1 (col2)
                for xml path ('')
               ), 1, 1, ''
             ) ;
```

Comment: @MatBailie. . . Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. Finally i found that query too. Is there a way to query like that in Oracle Query?

Answer (score 0):

May be this one for Oracle?

```
WITH tmp AS
(
  SELECT 'Frank' Name, 'London' City FROM dual 
  UNION
  SELECT 'Sebastian', 'New York' FROM dual
)
SELECT LISTAGG(name||';'||city, '; ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY null) FROM tmp
```